# Recursion. nCr and nPr code. Giving out weird answers

Tags: java, recursion

```
public class PermComb {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Insert n");        int n=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Insert r");        int r=input.nextInt();

    double C = factorial(n)/(factorial(n-r)*factorial(r));     //Finding C.
        System.out.println("Therefore: nCr = " + C);

    double P = factorial(n)/(factorial(n-r));                  //Finding P.
        System.out.println("Therefore: nPr = " + P);
}
public static double factorial(double num) {
    if(num==1)  return 1;
    else        return num = factorial(num-1)*num;
}
```

Now it's giving out weird answers on set on values like (20,10), (30,15), (19,8), (20,2).

Why? Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it overflows. Use `long` instead, or `BigInteger`.

Comment: Used double. Didn't help.

Comment: Which answer did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: When i insert (20,10), I get nCr = 11.0 and nPr = -579.0.

Comment: factorial(30) far exceeds 2^31 - 1 (which is an int max value), and even 2^63 - 1 (which is a long max value). Use BigInteger.

Comment: I should get 184756 and 6.7x10^11 respectively.

Comment: @JBNizet What about (20,2) then?

Comment: factorial(20) is also much bigger than 2^31-1 (please dont't ask for 19. Use your calculator to find out).

Comment: @jbnizet Now I changed it to double. It's still not working.

Comment: What is so hard to understand in "Use BigInteger"? double != BigInteger. double sucks at representing large integer numbers.

Answer (score 2):

That is because of overflows.  The maximum number you can store in an int (32 bit) is 2^31 - 1 which is about 2 billion. For a long (64 bit) it would be 2^63 - 1.

To calculate something like 30!, you need at least 108 bits. 
(base 2 logarithm of 30! is 107.7..)

I would strongly suggest you using java.math.BigInteger class for these kind of calculations.

*Note:* To store the result of 30 C 15, a long will be sufficient. But for the calculation, you need to find 30!. You might be able to avoid finding 30! and still find 30 C 15 using long with some clever algorithm.

A solution with BigInteger is given below.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

...

public static BigInteger factorial(int num) {
    if(num == 0)  return BigInteger.ONE;
    else        return factorial(num - 1).multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(num));
}

public static BigInteger nCr(int n, int r){
    return factorial(n).divide(factorial(n-r).multiply(factorial(r));
}
```

You can call them like this,

```
BigInteger C = nCr(30, 15);
System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: No. Double is worse than long for these kind of integer calculations.

Answer (score 1):

The factorial function overflows the range for `int` already at 13, so you will not be able to use the formula that uses factorials directly. Instead, expand the factorials and compute nCk from the alternative definition:

```
nCk = n*(n-1)*...*(n-k+1) / k*(k-1)*...*2*1
```

Comment: It will "work" in a sense: the result will be imprecise rather than completely wrong. An implementation that is both correct and efficient doesn't try to compute factorials at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use `long`

```
/**
 * @author Rakesh KR
 *
 */
public class New {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        int n=10, r=1;
        long ncr,npr;
        ncr = find_ncr(n,r);
        npr = find_npr(n,r);
        System.out.println(ncr+"---"+npr);

    }
    static long find_ncr(int n,int r){
        return factorial(n)/(factorial(r)*factorial(n-r));
    }
    static long find_npr(int n,int r){
        return factorial(n)/factorial(n-r);
    } 
    static long factorial(int n){
        return n==0?1:n*factorial(n-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `long` will overflow. Take `int n=30, r=15;` per example, `factorial(30) > Long.MAX_VALUE`